# Custom position for UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm currently trying to implement UISearchController and its associated UISearchBar.
I aim to have a UISearchBar just above my UITableView which goes top as soon as it has the focus, like the picture below (screenshot from my old UI with UISearchDisplayController, now deprecated):
[image: UISearchDisplayController screenshot]

I already tried to set my UISearchBar as header of the UITableView, it works well but I have 2 issues :

1. The search bar logically scrolls with the table view content
2. When the search bar takes the focus, it remains at the same position

Here is the way I configured my UISearchBar:

```
func configureSearchController() { // Method called in the viewDidLoad()
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController!.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController!.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController!.searchBar.placeholder = "searchfood.searchbar.placeholder".localized
    searchController!.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchController!.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    print(searchController!.searchBar.frame)

    // Place the search bar view to the tableview headerview.
    foodsTableView.tableHeaderView = searchController!.searchBar

    // Search bar
    searchController!.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .prominent
    searchController!.searchBar.barTintColor = ColorLSDP.corail
    searchController!.searchBar.tintColor = ColorLSDP.beige
}
```

So I tried to remove the following lines:

```
foodsTableView.tableHeaderView = searchController!.searchBar
```

But when I did this, I was not able to see the UISearchBar anymore. 
After checking some other SO topics, I just spotted that my UISearchBar was maybe hidden below my UINavigationBar. So I tried to add the following lines in the viewDidLoad() method:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```

It changed nothing.
Anyway, it did not solve my main issue which is having this search bar initially positioned like the screenshot above.

Is there a way to do this properly with the brand new UISearchController ?

Thanks a lot for your upcoming answers,
Regards,
Seb R.

Comment: An other question that could help me to have more time to find answers: the following warning leads me to try UISearchController:
"'searchDisplayController' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 8.0".
Does it mean Apple will refuse my new release if I keep UISearchDisplayController instances in my app ?